# Does reclining the front or back seat of a car reduce the effectiveness of the seat belt?

Tags: effectiveness, vehicle-car-accident, recumbent-lying-down, crash-test-dummies

I wonder whether reclining the front or back seat of a car reduces the effectiveness of the seat belt in case of an accident.

Example of reclined front seats:

[image]

Example of a reclined back seat:

[image]

Comment: Given the forces involved, I think It would make it possible for someone to slide out from under the seat belts in a crash. It might also increase the chances of leg and hip fractures if the car crumples heavily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

[The effect of reclined seats on mortality in motor vehicle collisions.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18332800)

> The reclined position is associated with increased occupant mortality
>   in motor vehicle collisions.

Why?

> flexion and compression injuries over pretensioned lap and shoulder
>   belts resulted in severe thoracoabdominal and spine injuries in
>   restrained occupants, with a high associated mortality. Increased
>   lower extremity injuries from additional force loads into bolsters and
>   panels were also noted.

[Seatbelt effectiveness](https://www.avvo.com/legal-guides/ugc/did-you-know-that-reclining-in-your-seat-can-be-deadly)

- > If your car seat is reclined, a three-point restraint (lap and
  >   shoulder seat belt) becomes esentially useless because the shoulder
  >   harness moves away from the passenger. Seat belts do not work -- and,
  >   in fact, can make injuries worse -- if they are not properly designed (proper "seat belt geometry") or not properly worn.
- > Few people understand that the more space between the seat belt and
  >   the passenger's chest increases the risk of death or serious injury
  >   caused when your body either slams against the seat belt itself or
  >   "submarines" and slides beneath the seat belt.

So yes, this is just a few ways reclining the seat can reduce the effectiveness of the seatbelt.